# Balanceamento de parênteses

Tags: c

Estou fazendo uma atividade de programação em C envolvendo TAD e PILHA. A proposta da minha atividade é fazer uma biblioteca (`pilha.c`) utilizando apenas as funções da `pilha.h`.

Na `lisp.c`, devo fazer com que o meu programa receba do usuário a quantidade de caracteres, um numero para saber que nivel está determinado caractere e a frase, tendo como resposta se a frase está balanceada entre os parênteses. Caso sim, dizer qual nível está o caracter na frase. Caso não esteja balanceada, apenas informar que não está. Por exemplo:

> (((a)(b)c))
>
> 7 caracteres
>
> Caractere 2
>
> Resposta do programa: A frase está balanceada e o caracter b está no nível 3.

`lisp.c`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "pilha.h"

int main(){
    int QtCar, idx, lvl;
    char charlvl[10];

    printf("Quantidade de caracteres:\n");
    scanf("%d",&QtCar);

    char Fr[QtCar];
    printf("Frase:\n");
    scanf("%s",Fr);

    printf("Verificar caracter no nivel?\n");
    scanf("%d",&idx);

    Pilha lisp = create();

    for(int i=0; i<QtCar;i++){
        if (Fr[i] == '(')
            push(&lisp, Fr[i]);
        if (Fr[i] == ')'){
            if (isEmpty(lisp)){
                printf ("A lista nao esta balanceada");
                break;
            }
            else
                pop(&lisp);
        }
        if (idx == 1){
            lvl = size(lisp);
            charlvl[1] = Fr[i];
        }
        else
            idx--;
    }
    if (isEmpty(lisp))
        printf ("A lista está balanceada! %s está no lvl %d",charlvl[1],lvl);
    else
        printf ("A lista nao esta balanceada");
}
```

`pilha.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "pilha.h"

Pilha create(){
    Pilha p;
    p->topo = -1;
    p->elementos[MAX];
}

int isFull(Pilha p){
    if (p->topo == MAX-1)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}

char pop(Pilha *p){
    char c = p->elementos[p->topo];
    p->topo--;
    return c;
}

void push(Pilha *p, char c){
    if (isFull(p))
        return 0;
    else{
        p->topo++;
        char p->elementos[p->topo] = c;
        return 1;
    }
}
int isEmpty(Pilha p){
    if (p->topo == -1)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;

}

int size(Pilha p){
    int tam;
    tam = p->topo; + 1;
    return tam;
}
```

`pilha.h`:

```
#ifndef PILHA_H_
#define PILHA_H_

#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX 100

typedef struct pilha {
    char elementos[MAX];
    int topo;
} Pilha;

Pilha create(); //cria pilha
char pop(Pilha *p); //desempilha
void push(Pilha *p, char c); //empilha
int isEmpty(Pilha p); //verifica pilha vazia
int isFull(Pilha p); //verifica pilha cheia
int size(Pilha p); //verifica tamanho da pilha

#endif
```

Sendo assim, estou tendo vários problemas. Inicialmente não estou conseguindo compilar, mas gostaria de saber onde posso estar melhorando o algoritmo.

Comment: Esta pergunta tem dois votos para fechar. Um destes votos como "*ampla demais*" e o outro como "*não está claro o suficiente*". Discordo desses votos de fechamento e votei por "*deixar aberta*". Alguém que é a favor do fechamento gostaria de explicar melhor?

Answer (score 1):

1. Boa parte dos seus erros de compilação é que ora você usa `Pilha` e ora usa `Pilha *`. Use sempre `Pilha *`.
2. Veja a sua função de criar pilhas:

   ```
   Pilha create() {
       Pilha p;
       p->topo = -1;
       p->elementos[MAX];
   }
   ```

   O uso de `->` serve para acessar ponteiros, então `p` deveria ser um ponteiro. Além disso, você deveria retornar um ponteiro (tal como disse no item 1). Se `p` não for um ponteiro, ele vai ser alocado na pilha e desalocado quando a função terminar, então você tem que alocá-lo no *heap* com `malloc`. Você deveria então fazer isso:

   ```
   Pilha *create() {
       Pilha *p = (Pilha *) malloc(sizeof(Pilha));
       p->topo = -1;
       p->elementos[MAX];
       return p;
   }
   ```

   Entretanto, esse `p->elementos[MAX];` não faz nada. O que você queria em seu lugar era isso:

   ```
       for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
           p->elementos[i] = 0;
       }
   ```
3. Sua função `push` é `void`, mas ela tem um `return 0;` e um `return 1;` dentro. Vamos fazer retornar `int`.
4. Na sua função `push` temos isso:

   ```
   char p->elementos[p->topo] = c;
   ```

   Esse `char` aí na frente não serve para nada. Retire-o.
5. Com as mudanças acima, no arquivo `lisp.c`, esssas linhas:

   ```
   Pilha lisp = create();
   push(&lisp, Fr[i]);
   pop(&lisp);
   ```

   Passam a ficar assim:

   ```
   Pilha *lisp = create();
   push(lisp, Fr[i]);
   pop(lisp);
   ```

Com essas mudanças, o seu código já deve compilar. Mas ainda assim há outros erros:

6. Veja a sua função `size`:

   ```
   int size(Pilha p) {
       int tam;
       tam = p->topo; + 1;
       return tam;
   }
   ```

   Acerca do `*` antes do `p`, já falei antes. Mas olhe a linha `tam = p->topo; + 1;` - há um ponto-e-vírgula a mais aí! Além disso, você não precisa dessa variável se você já vai retornar imediatamente. Logo, dá para simplificar tudo isso assim:

   ```
   int size(Pilha *p) {
       return p->topo + 1;
   }
   ```
7. Vejamos sua função `isEmpty`:

   ```
   int isEmpty(Pilha p){
       if (p->topo == -1)
           return 1;
       else
           return 0;

   }
   ```

   O resultado de uma comparação com `==` é sempre 1 quando ela é verdadeira e 0 quando não é. Logo, se o resultado da comparação for 1, deve-se retornar 1, se for 0, deve-se retornar 0. Logo, é mais simples apenas retornar o resultado da comparação diretamente:

   ```
   int isEmpty(Pilha *p) {
       return p->topo == -1;
   }
   ```

   O mesmo pode ser feito na sua função `isFull`.
8. Se você tem um `if` que sempre termina com um `return`, o `else` é desnecessário. Por exemplo:

   ```
   if (condição) {
       return alguma_coisa;
   } else {
       blablabla
   }
   ```

   É equivalente a isso:

   ```
   if (condição) {
       return alguma_coisa;
   }
   blablabla
   ```

   Com isso em mente, você pode simplificar a sua função `push` ao eliminar o `else` dela.
9. O caso da variável `charlvl` é curioso. Isso é um array de 10 posições, mas você só utiliza a posição 1. Logo, é melhor declarar isso como um `char`. Além disso, há um `printf` onde você imprime `charlvl[1]` usando `%s`. Você deveria usar `%c`. Além disso, a menos que a lista esvazie antes de ele chegar na posição do caractere procurado, teremos que `charlvl[1]` será `Fr[idx - 1]`. Assim sendo, é melhor mudar essa variável para o tipo `char` e atribuir `Fr[idx - 1]` a ela antes do `for`.
10. Você vai decrementando o `idx` até que quando ele for 1, você execute o `lvl = size(lisp);`. O `idx` vai ter o valor 1 apenas quando `i == lvl - 1`. Logo, é mais fácil você colocar essa condição no `if`, não mudar a variável `lvl` nunca e se livrar do `else`.
11. Você pede para verificar caracteres em um determinado nível. Na verdade, o que você olha é em uma determinada posição na frase. Assim sendo, a mensagem correspondente no `printf` deve ser alterada. A variável `idx` é a posição do caractere na frase.
12. Uma coisa muito importante em programação é dar nomes adequados a variáveis. Em especial se você está na faculdade, por que de vez em quando alguns professores pegam no pé e até tiram ponto se o programa tiver variáveis com nomes inadequados ou despadronizados. Assim sendo, sugiro você renomear `Fr` para `frase`, `QtCar` para `quantidade`, `idx` para `posicao`, `lvl` para `nivel` e `charlvl` para `procurado`.
13. O `printf("A lista nao esta balanceada");` dentro do `for` do `main` não deveria estar lá. Ele já diz se a lista está ou não balanceada no final. Entretanto, a ideia aqui é interromper toda a análise. Então uma variável auxiliar que indique se a análise foi ou não abortada neste ponto se faz necessário.
14. Você não precisa de `stdio.h` dentro de `pilha.c` e nem de `pilha.h`. E também não precisa de `stdlib.h` dentro de `lisp.c`.

Eis como fica então o seu programa:

`pilha.h`:

```
#ifndef PILHA_H_
#define PILHA_H_

#define MAX 100

typedef struct pilha {
    char elementos[MAX];
    int topo;
} Pilha;

Pilha *create(); //cria pilha
char pop(Pilha *p); //desempilha
int push(Pilha *p, char c); //empilha
int isEmpty(Pilha *p); //verifica pilha vazia
int isFull(Pilha *p); //verifica pilha cheia
int size(Pilha *p); //verifica tamanho da pilha

#endif
```

`pilha.c`:

```
#include "pilha.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

Pilha *create() {
    Pilha *p = (Pilha *) malloc(sizeof(Pilha));
    p->topo = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
        p->elementos[i] = 0;
    }
    return p;
}

int isFull(Pilha *p) {
    return p->topo == MAX - 1;
}

char pop(Pilha *p) {
    char c = p->elementos[p->topo];
    p->topo--;
    return c;
}

int push(Pilha *p, char c) {
    if (isFull(p)) {
        return 0;
    }
    p->topo++;
    p->elementos[p->topo] = c;
    return 1;
}

int isEmpty(Pilha *p) {
    return p->topo == -1;
}

int size(Pilha *p) {
    return p->topo + 1;
}
```

`lisp.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "pilha.h"

int main() {
    int quantidade, posicao, nivel;

    printf("Quantidade de caracteres:\n");
    scanf("%d", &quantidade);

    char frase[quantidade];
    printf("Frase:\n");
    scanf("%s", frase);

    printf("Verificar caracter na posicao?\n");
    scanf("%d", &posicao);
    char procurado = frase[posicao - 1];

    int abortado = 0;
    Pilha *lisp = create();

    for (int i = 0; i < quantidade; i++) {
        if (frase[i] == '(') {
            push(lisp, frase[i]);
        }
        if (frase[i] == ')') {
            if (isEmpty(lisp)) {
                abortado = 1;
                break;
            } else {
                pop(lisp);
            }
        }
        if (i == posicao - 1) {
            nivel = size(lisp);
        }
    }
    if (!abortado && isEmpty(lisp)) {
        printf("A lista esta balanceada! %c está no nivel %d", procurado, nivel);
    } else {
        printf("A lista nao esta balanceada");
    }
}
```

O seu programa deve então funcionar assim.

Entretanto, há ainda um segredinho: Uma vez que a única coisa que você empilha são abre-parênteses, logo, você pode eliminar a pilha e trocá-la por um contador. Isso mostra que esse exercício não precisa de fato usar uma pilha para verificar se os parênteses estão balanceados e uma solução mais simples existe. Isso também significa que o seu professor deveria bolar um outro exercício para pilhas que não pudesse ser resolvido sem utilizá-las. Eis como ficaria o seu programa sem usar pilhas:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int quantidade, posicao, nivel;

    printf("Quantidade de caracteres:\n");
    scanf("%d", &quantidade);

    char frase[quantidade];
    printf("Frase:\n");
    scanf("%s", frase);

    printf("Verificar caracter na posicao?\n");
    scanf("%d", &posicao);
    char procurado = frase[posicao - 1];

    int abortado = 0;
    int abertos = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < quantidade; i++) {
        if (frase[i] == '(') {
            abertos++;
        }
        if (frase[i] == ')') {
            if (abertos == 0) {
                abortado = 1;
                break;
            } else {
                abertos--;
            }
        }
        if (i == posicao - 1) {
            nivel = abertos;
        }
    }
    if (!abortado && abertos == 0) {
        printf("A lista esta balanceada! %c está no nivel %d", procurado, nivel);
    } else {
        printf("A lista nao esta balanceada");
    }
}
```